# How do I make a simple client/server app in two different projects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, server, client, client-server

I am trying to make a client-server game for school. We have to do two separate porjects in eclipse. One for the client and one for the server. The problem is whenever I try to connect the client to the server I get a java.net.BindException. Saying: Address already in use: JVM_Bind. Can anyone please tell me what to do or what I did wrong? Thank you!

This is my code for the client:

```
public class SimpleClient {

    private static final int PORT = 2345;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try(Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), PORT)) {
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the server:

```
public class GameServer implements Runnable {

    private static final int PORT = 2345;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("server ready!");
                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("welcome friend!");

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Thread(new GameServer()).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The server and the client should use the same port. Server pot is used for listening and the client port is used for connect to the Server. So change both of two ports to 4432.

Comment: Check what progress is using your port 4435 and kill it.

Comment: I've tried that and it still doesn't work